# Android dynamic spinner in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, spinner

i need help. I looked in other posts and try to do same but all solutions isn't working. I'm trying to make spinner with dynamic data, but always stop working...

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        final List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item 1");
        list.add("Item 2");
        list.add("Item 3");
        list.add("Item 4");
        list.add("Item 5");

        Spinner s = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(this.getActivity(), R.array.spinnerItems, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.spinnerItems, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        s.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Please, how to make it running?

Comment: post your logcat plz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, locations);
  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  s.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

and make sure your Fragment successfully attached to your activity so that `getActivity()` not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, we should call `getActivity()` in or after `onActivityCreated()`, as before then it will return `null`.

So, move the code to bind spinner options in `onActivityCreated()` and see what happens.

Also, if you can post the error log, it will help other to suggest good solutions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In place of `this.getActivity()`     replace `getActivity() 
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, locations);`